# differences in assigning pointers to vector

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, and I've seen a code like this

```
std::vector<Element*> *interactedElems
```

Where `Element` is a class.
But not sure sure about the differences in the following cases:

1. `std::vector<Element> *interactedElems`
2. `std::vector<Element*> interactedElems`
3. `std::vector<Element*> *interactedElems`
4. `std::vector<Element*> ＆ interactedElems`

Comment: Behind the scenes, pointers are fairly important to CPU's. C++ gives you direct access. However, we find that it's often not necessary to deal _directly_ with pointers. `std::vector<Element>` will have a pointer internally, but you can safely ignore that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A `vector` of `Element`s**

```
std::vector<Element> elements;
```

You can add `Element`s to it. Assuming `Element` has default constructor, you can use:

```
elements.push_back(Element());
```

You can get the first `Element` from `elements` using:

```
Element e = elements[0];
```

**Pointer to a `vector` of `Element`s**

```
std::vector<Element>* elementsPointer;
```

In order to add `Element`s to `elementsPointer`, is has to point to something valid.

```
elementsPointer = new std::vector<Element>;
elementsPointer->push_back(Element());
```

You can get the first `Element` from `elementsPointer` using:

```
Element e = (*elementsPointer)[0];
```

or

```
Element e = elementsPointer->at(0);
```

**A `vector` of pointers to `Element`s**

```
std::vector<Element*> elementPointers;
```

You can add `Element*` to the `vector`.

```
elementPointers.push_back(new Element);
```

When you get the items from this `vector`, you get `Element*`s.

```
Element* ePtr = elementPointers[0];
```

**Pointer to a `vector` of pointers to `Element`s**

```
std::vector<Element*>* elementPointersPointer;
```

In order to add `Element` pointers to `elementPointersPointer`, is has to
point to something valid.

```
elementPointersPointer = new std::vector<Element*>;
elementPointersPointer->push_back(new Element);
```

You can get the first `Element*` from `elementPointersPointer` using:

```
Element* ePtr = (*elementPointersPointer)[0];
```

or

```
Element* ePtr = elementPointersPointer->at(0);
```

**Using a reference**

Using a reference to any of the above forms is just like using references to any other types in C++.

Use can use:

```
std::vector<Element> elements;
std::vector<Element>& elementsRef = elements;
```

or any of the other variants.

Answer (score 2):

1. is a pointer to a vector of Element objects.

The declaration itself is for a pointer to a container object.  It contains individual Element objects.

2. is a vector of pointers to Elements.

The declaration itself is for the container object.  It contains pointers, each pointing to an Element object.

3. is a pointer to a vector of pointers to Elements.

The declaration itself is a pointer.  It points to a vector, which contains more pointers.  These pointers are to actual element objects.

4. is a reference to a vector of pointers to Elements.

This is just like #3, except that it is a reference to a vector instead of a pointer.  A reference basically being a pointer that you can't re-point at something else.

Comment: in the first case, the declaration is not for a container, but for a pointer